# Trigonometry Question - With roots

Tags: trigonometry

> Show the equation $\tan^{-1}x$ = $kx$, where $k$ is a constant, has only one real root when $k<0$ and state its value.

I am not sure what to do here - Not sure where to start even. Any help appreciated.

Comment: $\tan^{-1}x$ is a strictly increasing function of $x$. If $k<0$ then $kx$ is a strictly decreasing function of $x$. They meet at $x=0.$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $f(x)=kx-\tan^{-1}x$; then $f(0)=0$ and
$$
f'(x)=k-\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{kx^2+k-1}{1+x^2}
$$
Write it as
$$
f'(x)=\frac{k}{1+x^2}(x^2+h)
$$
where $h=(k-1)/k>0$. Then $f'(x)<0$ for every $x$ and so the function is decreasing.

---

The same can be said if $k\ge1$: the derivative is positive except possibly at $0$ (for $k=1$), so the function is increasing. If $k=0$ the function is again decreasing. Thus the interesting part is for $0<k<1$.

If we set $a=\sqrt{(1-k)/k}$, the derivative is
$$
f'(x)=\frac{k}{1+x^2}(x^2-a^2)
$$
which is negative for $-a<x<a$. Hence the function has a local maximum at $-a$ and a local minimum at $x=a$. Since $f(0)=0$, the local maximum must be positive and the local minimum must be negative.

Moreover
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=-\infty
\qquad
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty
$$
and so the equation has three roots. Here's a picture for $k=1/2$:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Imagine graph of $y=\tan^{-1} x$
$$$$
 and it's intersection with$$$$
$y=kx$
$$$$
Where $k\lt 0$ ,
$$$$
Such line passes through origin and makes angle $\gt 90°$ with positive x-axis
$$$$

> [image]

Or $$$$
Say $k=-a$ such that $a\gt 0$
$$\tan^{-1} x=-ax$$

$$$$

> Here if $x\gt 0$$$$$
>   $$\tan^{-1} x\gt 0$$$$$$
>   $$ ax \lt 0$$$$$$
>   As $a\gt 0$$$$$
>   $$x\lt 0$$$$$$
>   This just contradicts what we said, so ,$$$$

$$x\not= -\tan ax \text{ for }x\gt 0$$$$$$
$$$$$$$$

> Here if $x\lt 0$$$$$
>   $$\tan^{-1} x\lt 0$$$$$$
>   $$ ax \gt 0$$$$$$
>   As $a\gt 0$$$$$
>   $$x\gt 0$$$$$$
>   This just contradicts what we said, so ,$$$$

$$x\not= -\tan ax \text{ for }x\lt 0$$$$$$
$$$$$$$$

> Now we find that the is no root in $x\not= 0$$$$$
>   So one root must lie in $x=0$$$$$
>   $$\tan^{-1} 0 =0$$$$$$
>   $$0=0$$$$$$

Which is true, hence the is only one root for the equation.

Comment: $\tan$ or $\tanh$?

Comment: tanh x . This sentence exists to fill in 15 characters

Comment: $\tanh$ is not the same thing as $\tan^{-1},$ although the graphs have some similar features (strictly increasing, horizontal asymptotes, odd functions) and give the same result to the root of $f(x) = -|k|x.$ So technically the graph is wrong, but all you need to do to fix it is replace the wrong function by the correct one; the rest of the analysis is the same.

Comment: Sorry not tanh x i meant to say arctan x

Comment: question itself mentions $\tan^{-1} x$ ,

Comment: I know tanh x is hyperbolic function and arctan x is inverse of tan x, so i meant arctan x

Comment: Right, so the correct graph will have asymptotes at $\pm\frac\pi2$ rather than at $\pm1,$ for example. Otherwise it's fine.

Comment: It has no asymptotes at $\pm 1$

Comment: It just looks like that but it's asymptotes are at $\pm \frac{π}{2} $ only

Answer (score 0):

The question is incorrect. Apart from the $x=0$ solution there are infinitely many roots/ solutions that can be found only by numerical iteration.

[image: Rough Handsketch]

Comment: It's the arctangent, not the tangent.

Comment: Indeed, it is also seen on graph..

Comment: $k$ is a constant.

Comment: Yes,so $y=-kx$ are str. lines through origin

Comment: Oh! You're using the multivalued arctangent! That's naughty.

Comment: All inverse trig functions r naughty :)